# The Color Taste

Tags: riddle

> **Name the blue when definitely looks red, but is rather green in fact?**

Hint:

> If you can name more choose the bluest one!

Comment: Should "when" be "which"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Better no

Comment: If I said this out loud, I'd think I was having a stroke.

Comment: What color is DEF? It's called "AdBlue" by some marketing guys... the same marketing guys who call it "green" during their daily greenwashing exercise.

Comment: The veins inside a human body. They are red because of the blood inside them, they were drawn blue in my biology books and they might as well be green because I have [daltonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness). :)

Comment: I agree with @JonathanAllan. Now that I've seen the answer, it just makes more sense to have proper grammar and use "which" or "that" instead of "when".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had some

> Blueberries

and they seem to fit since

> They are called blue and are blue on the outside, yet when smeared look [red](http://www.tablecrafter.com/uploads/ckeditor/pictures/1613/content_3D1A6255.jpg) and are red when they are ripening.  The blueberry plant is mainly green, and the berries are green before they ripen, many times are [green](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-1Q95jcHgxmM/UBS5oYn9eTI/AAAAAAAAHBM/6E0-KTEB5qY/s1600/blueberry+vegan+scones.jpg) inside but turn red when cooked.

and they fit the hint since

> They have blue in the single word name of this fruit.

Comment: That's the name. Just needs right explanation of "red" and "green"... without smashing them or doing anything else ;)

Comment: Yes, it is red while still green (i.e. while ripening).

Answer (score 13):

I think it might be

> a blue steak

because it definitely looks red inside and it is also green because

> it doesn't use as much energy to cook

Answer (score 9):

I'm gonna throw

> blue raspberry

out there

> it's a flavor associated with the color blue, named after something usually red, based on [something (mostly) green](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Rubus_leucodermis)

Answer (score 4):

Could it be

> Violet

Since

> Violet is of a shorter wavelength than what we actually call blue - lying between "blue" and "ultraviolet" (which we cannot see) and is hence really "bluer" than blue.
> Violet when observed by our eyes looks like a red-ish blue
> (In the traditional colour wheel used by painters, violet and purple lie between red and blue).
> In an RGB model a vivid violet would contain rather a surprising amount of Green.

Comment: Nice guess, but no. And does not fit all clues :)

Comment: I think it fits all the clues - I was wondering only about the use of "taste" in the title. Will have to think...

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Blue grape

since

> They are usually blue, the insides are green, when crushed together for wine and such, they are red.